# Could lex/flex be used to parse binary format source files?

Tags: parsing, text, binary, format, lex

When I learn lex tool, I found it helps to parse source files in text format, like building a new programming languages, etc. I also with to use it to build a tool to analyse some binary input streams, like codec/decoders.

Does lex/flex/yacc/bison support such requirements, do they have special command line options and syntax to enable this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex (and the other lex implentations I'm familiar with) have no problem with non-ascii characters, including the NUL character. You may have to use the `8bit` option, although it is the default unless you request fast state tables.

However, most binary formats use length-prefixed variable length fields, which cannot be expressed in a regular expression. Moreover, it is quite common for fixed-lengtb fields to be context-dependent; you can build a state machine in flex using start conditions, but that's a lot of work and is likely to be a waste of your time and flex's features.

Comment: Which tool would you recommend for binary files with "length-prefixed variable length" fields instead of lex then?